# Python, calculating family tree depth from one member to another

Tags: python, recursion

I have a dictionary with family tree data(key - name of a person, it's value - children).
I'd like to recursively get a depth from one given member to another (get_depth(from_person, to_person)).

Comment: Pick your poison: Breadth-First Search or Depth-First Search

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Regarding method used (depth-first or breadth -first) i'd prefeer depth first, but more is better since I'm trying to understand both:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would choose DFS, since it makes keeping track of the depth easy.

```
def get_depth(root, target):
    if root == target:
        return 0
    if not d[root]:
        return None
    for child in d[root]:
        depth = get_depth(child, target)
        if depth is not None:
            return 1 + depth
    return None
```

The last `return` is strictly speaking unnecessary, but I prefer to spell these things out. Feel free to ask any questions, but this should be fairly self-explanatory.  You might feel more comfortable replacing `None` with `-1` and then checking `if depth >= 0`